# Proof of $x^n(1-x)$ uniformly converges to $0$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I attempted to prove $x^n(1-x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$ but I'm not sure if my proof is right.

*My proof is*:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then we can find $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $N > 2/\epsilon$. For all $x \in  [0,1)$ if $n\ge N$ we have $$|f_n(x)-0| = |x^n(1-x)| \le |x|^n(1+|x|) \le 2x^n\le2x^N\le2N<\epsilon$$ and if $x=1$, for all $n\ge N, \quad |f_n(x)-0| = |0-0| = 0\le\epsilon$. So $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Is my proof correct? Thank you!

Comment: You choose $N > 2/\epsilon$ and then you use $2N < \epsilon$ so it is clearly incorrect.

Comment: The estimate $f_n(x) \leq 2x^n$ is not strong enough to proof uniform convergence, as $2x^n$ itself does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $|f_n(x) - 0| = x^n(1-x)$ attains a maximum at $x^* = n/(n+1)$ where $$f_n(x^*) = \frac{1}{(n+1/n)^n(n+1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof has a mistake.
$2x^N < \varepsilon$ is not given since $\lim_{x\to1}x^N = 1$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$.